# How to decide warning and critical levels in nagios?

Tags: nagios, icinga

> Can someone please tell on what basis should I decide warning and critical level for a check in nagios . I want to  have notification for warning state before the check sends out critical . The check I am performing is check_es_logs that is Elastic Search logs.Performance data is below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Warning and Critical thresholds are plugin-specific, which means that they are set in your check command. The plugin decides what state it should return (technically which exit code) based on the thresholds that you pass with flags to it, normally `-w` and `-c`.

If you want a more specific answer you need to ask a more specific question. For example:

> I want to have notification for warning state before the check sends out critical

This doesn't make a lot of sense to me since you would just end up with two notifications, one saying Warning and one saying Critical.

You can do additional filtering, for example by saying that a contact should only receive notifications of a certain state, but since I don't know what you want your exact end result to be I'm not sure what to suggest.

Also, Icinga is a very different product from Nagios Core for example, so if this is an Icinga specific question it should not be tagged Nagios as the syntax for config files etc. will likely differ a lot.